# How can I rewrite my method to async/await?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, async-await, axios

In my react app I'm making a post request to the server with the help of axios:

```
 onSubmit = (results) => {
     axios.post("http://localhost:8080/simulate/", results)
      .then( (response) => this.setState({results: response.data.results}))
      .catch( (error) => this.setState({results: error.response.data, hasError: true})
      ); 
  }
```

**How can I rewrite this method to `async/await`?**

Comment: You can used request-promise which will be async in nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onSubmit = async (results) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/simulate/", results)
    this.setState({results: response.data.results})
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({results: error.response.data, hasError: true})
  }
}
```

### Edit - without Axios

If you don't want to use Axios, you may use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
onSubmit = async (results) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/simulate/", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(results)
    })
    const { data } = await response.json()
    this.setState({results: data.results})
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({results: error.response.data, hasError: true})
  }
}
```

Comment: can I don't use axios at all?

Comment: @Leocete you can use the Fetch-api. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I receive `OK` in my response from server, but not data

Comment: is your server sending back json our plain text ?